# HandwritingRecognitionOperation import from projectoxford is not working anymore

Tags: java, android, import, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run the sample app from Microsoft's cognitive service (computer vision). I am wondering why is the handwriting import not working? It says "cannot resolve symbol".

```
import com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.contract.HandwritingRecognitionOperation;
import com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.contract.HandwritingRecognitionOperationResult;
import com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.contract.HandwritingTextLine;
import com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.contract.HandwritingTextWord;
```

Comment: Probably because it can't resolve a symbol. This is common when trying to parse non-English rare character, like stuff from Poland such as the Polish whitespace. At any rate, this is nowhere near enough information to analyze the problem properly.

Comment: Hi @G_V Thanks for the reply! I solved it by updating the project's dependency to it's latest version.

Comment: Great! Can you add the problem you had to the question and answer it yourself so others running into this issue can find it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by updating projectoxford library dependency on build.gradle file. I think the HandwritingRecognitionOperation class is available only at version 1.0.394.

```
//Add Library
compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:vision:1.0.394'
```